# Dynamic text in email

Tags: html, email

I'd like to make a system where you can send emails with dynamic content. For instance, let's say I regret an email that I just sent and I want to delete that last paragraph out of it.

My first idea is to link (not embed) an image that loads from my server, and since I have control of that server I can change the image. The image would basically be a screenshot of whatever rendered HTML I was looking to send. It would have text, images, etc. but the only thing they receive in their inbox is a single image.

This question identifies the difference between linking and embedding: [Images in email: link or embed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429358/images-in-email-link-or-embed)

However, this is kind of obnoxious to the receiver because they can't select the text. Is there a way to link text/HTML/anything besides an image?

Comment: Nothing in the email content can be changed once the mail is sent.  Your best shot is a static hyperlink to an external resource on a web server.  Which you can change to your heart's content.   But bear in mind that this whole concept is flawed.  I would just say review your emails more carefully before sending.

Comment: "static hyperlink to an external resource on a web server"

Yep, that's what I was getting at with the image part, is there a way to make the static link load text/html in the email instead of an image?

Comment: Many have tried sending iframes via email (Google it), but it's neither practical nor technically feasible in some respects.

Comment: Interesting, I'll do some more research. Thanks isherwood

Comment: Even if this were possible, which I really don't think it is on any robust level, my personal opinion is that there are many negatives to this approach. From simply confusing the recipients, to losing their trust, and even has legal implications if it is misused.  But nonetheless I would be interested to hear of any success with this.  Good luck :)